# What is the best comparison algorithm for comparing the similarity of arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, image, algorithm, image-processing

I am building a program that takes 2 arrays and returns some value showing to what degree they are similar. For example, images with few differences will have a good score, whereas images that are vastly different will have a worse score.

So far the only two algorithms I have come across for this problem are the sum of the squared differences and the normalized correlation.

Both of these will be fairly simple to implement, however I was wondering if there was another algorithm I haven't been able to find that I could use?

Furthermore, which previously mentioned method will be the best? Would be great to know both in terms of their accuracy and efficiency.

Thanks,

Comment: I'd change the title and drop the last bit of the question as they drive the question into opinion and off topic. For example, to me, the best one is the one that is easiest to understand and maintain while meeting the required performance targets.

Comment: what kind of images are you dealing with? are this images black-white, grey-scale etc?

Comment: Oops my bad, these images are greyscale.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer. Your application will define what it means for two images to be similar. Should lightened and darkened versions of the same image be similar? Should a jpeg-compressed version of the same image be similar? Should the same image padded by some black space be similar? Stretched? Rotated? 0.1% of pixels randomly replaced with black? You need to ask yourself these questions before you can possibly call one similarity metric "best".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing images usually depends on application you are dealing with. Normally distance functions used depends on image descriptor.

Take look  at **Distance functions**

1. Euclidean Distance
2. Squared Euclidean Distance
3. Cosine Distance or Similarity   [THIS SHOULD WORK FINE]
4. Sum of Absolute Differences
5. Sum of Squared Differences
6. Correlation Distance
7. Hellinger Distance

*Grid Distance*

8. Manhattan Distance
9. Chebyshev Distance

*statistics distance function*

10. Wasserstein Metric

    11. Mahalanobis Distance
    12. Bray Curtis Distance
    13. Canberra Distance

*Binary Distance functions*

14. L0 Norm
15. Jacard similarity
16. Hamming Distance

As you are directly comparing images, taking cosine similarity should work for you.

Comment: What is this, a "parade of knowledge of distance names"? "Sum of Absolute Differences", "Manhattan distance" and "L0" is the same distance under 3 different names. "Sum of squared diffs" doesn't offer more insight than euclidian dist. "Hamming" is applicable to strings rather than 2D.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi that is my bad. i made edit. I was clearing intent of taking *similarity*. Distincition was made to point of descriptors intent. in case of manhattan distance is was grid distance.[ differs from multi-variate vectors] . Also you point about Hamming is true. Hamming is defined for strings. In Images, our descriptors are very often binary vectors i.e. string of 1 and 0. hence this has importance here.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing images well is *quite* non-trivial.

Just for one example, to get meaningful results you'll need to account for misalignment between the images being compared. If you just compare (for example) the top-left pixel in one image with the top-left pixel in the other, a fairly minor misalignment between the two can make those pixels entirely different, even though a person looking at the images would have difficulty seeing any difference at all.

One way to deal with this would be to start with something similar to the motion compensation used by MPEG 4. That is, break each image into small blocks (e.g., MPEG using 16x16 pixel blocks) and compare blocks in one to blocks in the other. This can eliminate (or at least drastically reduce) the effects of misalignment between the images.